# URL syntax in SSIS Derived Column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I need some assistance with the syntax of a system URL for a SSIS Derived Column. I have triple checked the package fields `CO_ID` and `ProcessNo`, so I must be missing something in the URL syntax.

```
"<a href=\"" + "https://pub.mickle.com /orders/Subsystem/Utils/RequestDoo.asp?ID=" + ORDER No class="nounderline" title="">" + "Order No" + CO_ID + ProcessNo + "</a>"
```

Any assistance to guide me into the light is appreciated

Comment: Please don't ask a question without explaining the issue. Do you get an error? Does it have an incorrect result? If so, what is the correct result?

Comment: @DavidF did you tried my suggestion? Always give a feedback to get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues in this expression:

- Additional space after the `.com` domain : `https://pub.mickle.com /orders`
- Double quotes escapes missing.
- Missing Bracket around Columns names *(because columns names like `ORDER No` contains spaces)*

I think you are looking for the following expression:

```
"<a href=\"https://pub.mickle.com/orders/Subsystem/Utils/RequestDoo.asp?ID=" + [ORDER No] + " class=\"nounderline\" title=\"\"> Order No" + [CO_ID] + [ProcessNo] + "</a>"
```

Also, if `[ORDER No]`, `[CO_ID]` or `[ProcessNo]` are numeric columns then you should use CAST operation:

```
"<a href=\"https://pub.mickle.com/orders/Subsystem/Utils/RequestDoo.asp?ID=" + (DT_WSTR,50)[ORDER No] + " class=\"nounderline\" title=\"\"> Order No" + (DT_WSTR,50)[CO_ID] + (DT_WSTR,50)[ProcessNo] + "</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks Hadi! Your syntax example was spot on.

Comment: Hadi, I thought you may want to see the final URL. Thanks again for your response.

    "<a href=\"" + "https://pub.mickle.com/orders/Subsystem/Utils/RequestDoo.asp?ID=" + OrderNumber + "\"" + " class=\"nounderline\"" + " title=\"\"" + ">" + "Order No" + CO_ID + " " + ProcessNo + "</a>"

Comment: i think you are missing a double quotation after `&qu‌​ot;` -->  `"<a href=\"" + "pub.mickle.com/orders/Subsystem/Utils/RequestDoo.asp?ID=&qu‌​ot;" + OrderNumber + "\"" + " class=\"nounderline\"" + " title=\"\"" + ">" + "Order No" + CO_ID + " " + ProcessNo + "</a>"`